# Shellshock protection in Rackspace Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, rackspace, bug

I am trying to update my Ubuntu 13.10 servers in Rackspace to avoid Shellshock bug, but it is not working. Here is what I am doing:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade bash
```

it says:

```
bash is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.

$ env VAR='() { :;}; echo Bash is vulnerable!' bash -c "echo Bash Test"
Bash is vulnerable!
Bash Test
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? What apt repos are you using?

Comment: I'm also seeing this same issue on a Ubuntu digital ocean droplet...

Comment: Ah, it turns out that the machine I'm trying to update is on an old version of Ubuntu. Please see my [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/631819/46432)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you are on a supported version of Ubuntu!

Anything that is EOL does not receive the bash update, as far as I'm aware.
If you are on Ubuntu 14.04, you *should* receive the update.

Anything like 13.10, however, does not from what I can tell.
Please upgrade Ubuntu and then update try updating bash, that will hopefully help!

Comment: Do I need to Update the whole distribution? I would want to only update the bash security hole

Comment: @DanielCukier - Yes, if you are using an EOL Ubuntu version I don't believe there is any way to get security fixes.